# how can i limit a value into a jtextfield without use a button?

Tags: java, input, jtextfield

How can I limit a value (int) into a `jtextfield` in Java? Without `Jbutton` or something like that, I want do this in the input of the textfield. I have tried use `evt.getkeychar` but this gives me only the value of a single character.

Comment: Please clarify, do you wish to limit within a numerical range, e.g. 1-15, or just block non-numeric characters?

Comment: basic editorial - fixed grammar and spelling

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can add key listener to the [`JTextField`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html) and override the keyreleased method. In the method, check if the there are non-digit characters in the text, if there are, get rid of them.

```
public class LimitInputValue {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame jframe = new JFrame();

        final JTextField jTextField = new JTextField();

        jframe.add(jTextField);
        jframe.pack();
        jframe.setVisible(true);

        jTextField.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
                String value = jTextField.getText();
                if (value == null || value.isEmpty()) return;
                String newValue = "";
                for (int i = 0; i < value.length(); ++i) {
                    if (Character.isDigit(value.charAt(i))) {
                        newValue += value.charAt(i);

                    }
                }
                jTextField.setText(newValue);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: no, i just do this, i wanna control the numeric value into the jtextfield, and if the value is more hight,delete it

Comment: @fenigo69 more hight? could you clarify a bit more by giving a couple examples?

Comment: sì, mi dispiace, forse non mi spiego good, esempi: (`se il numero nel campo di testo> 7) evt.consume; `

Comment: can you speak English?

Comment: yeah, sorry but google translate have translated automatically the comment.... i say "maybe i don't explain good,example:(`if the number in the textfield >7) evt.consume; `

Comment: i know, but i have understan only now

Comment: @fenigo69 okay, if the answer helped, would you consider accepting it?

Comment: yeah,sorry i forgotten it